# Colored ball problem combinations distribution

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

If you have an urn with $4$ balls each of red, white, blue and black, what is the probability distribution of getting drawing $4$ balls and getting exactly $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$, or $4$ red balls?

My attempts to calculate combinations for drawing exactly $1$ red balls is as follows: $$\binom{4}{1}\binom{12}{3}$$ where $\binom{4}{1}$ counts the number of ways of selecting one red balls and $\binom{12}{3}$ counts the number of ways of selecting three of the other twelve balls, with a result of $4\times220=880$.

I figure the total combinations would be $4^4$ or $256$, so I'm obviously on the wrong track.

Comment: Well, if you differentiate the balls (by numbering them say) as you did in your calculation (a good idea, by the way) then the total should be $\binom {16}4=1820$

Comment: $6 \times 220 = 1320$.

Comment: Worth remarking, $\binom {12}2=66$.  Not sure where your $220$ came from.  Nor the $880$, come to that.

Comment: so sorry, mixed factors of different distributions. In choosing exactly 1 red I would have 4 choose 1 = 4  x 12 choose 3=220 = 880. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: You can edit your question to fix that error by pressing the edit button at the bottom of your question.

Comment: Also, here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thank you for your responses and typeset assistance. I did arrive at 1,820 as sum of combinations  where the number of red balls = 0 through 4 inclusive. This approach seems consistent with other colored ball examples, yet I would expect the red ball distribution sum to be exactly 1/4 of the total combinations. I assume the total combinations to be 256

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lulu pointed out in the comments, the number of ways four of the sixteen balls can be selected is 
$$\binom{16}{4}$$

The number of ways of selecting exactly $k$ red balls when four balls are drawn from the urn is 
$$\binom{4}{k}\binom{12}{4 - k}$$
where $\binom{4}{k}$ is the number of ways of selecting $k$ of the four red balls and $\binom{12}{4 - k}$ is the number of ways of selecting $4 - k$ of the other $12$ balls in the urn.

Hence, the probability of selecting exactly $k$ red balls when four balls are drawn from the urn is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{4}{k}\dbinom{12}{4 - k}}{\dbinom{16}{4}}$$
where $0 \leq k \leq 4$.

Comment: Thank you both. My error is assuming that the total number of combinations is 256; I thought I should multiply 4 of each color with the product being 256. If these were playing cards, the total combinations for a hand of 2,3,4 and 5 with 4 available of each would be 256.I'm struggling to understand the distinction.

Comment: @Ally If you have sixteen distinct cards, the number of ways you can select a subset consisting of four of them is $\binom{16}{4}$ since we must choose which four of the sixteen cards to select.  On the other hand, if you wish to form sequences of length $4$ using digits selected from the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ with repetition, there are $4^4 = 256$ such sequences since we have four choices for each of the four positions in the sequence.  The number of functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \to \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ is also $256$ since we have four choices in the codomain for each element in the domain.